# Magento 2.4.2: Disable sales_grid_order_async_insert

Tags: magento2.4

Is disabling sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert, sales_grid_order_async_insert  sales_grid_order_creditmemo_async_insert and sales_grid_order_invoice_async_insert advisable from the perspective of site's performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how is your store configured with regards to the asynchronous indexing of the grids.

The configuration resides in  **Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Grid Settings > Asynchronous indexing**.

If it's disabled, then your crons won't process anything and by disabling them you won't gain any performance boost. As you can see below, the configuration is checked prior to processing:

```php
public function asyncInsert()
{
    if ($this->globalConfig->getValue('dev/grid/async_indexing')) {
        $this->entityGrid->refreshBySchedule();
    }
}
```

**However, this functionality is intended to actually help the performance of the checkout.** Check [this article](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048545492-Magento-best-practice-enable-asynchronous-orders-processing) which states that:

> If the number of simultaneously placed orders in your store is large enough and has a negative impact on checkout performance, we recommend enabling asynchronous orders processing.

You can disable it via Magerun by running the command below.

```
n98-magerun2 config:store:set dev/grid/async_indexing 0
```

Comment: Hi, do you suggest you keep it enabled,

Comment: I would at least try to see how it moves and see if it's worth it. Maybe in peak sales like black friday it helps.

Comment: I understand. thanks

Comment: You're welcome!